# F# multiple interface implementations with object expressions

Tags: f#

According to docs you can implement multiple interfaces with object expressions. But if you see below code :

```
// Define two interfaces
type IFirst =
  abstract F : unit -> unit
  abstract G : unit -> unit

type ISecond =
  abstract H : unit -> unit
  abstract J : unit -> unit

// This object expression implements both interfaces.
let implementer : IFirst =
    { new ISecond with
        member this.H() = ()
        member this.J() = ()
      interface IFirst with
        member this.F() = ()
        member this.G() = () }
```

So casting to `IFirst` causes a compiler error. Why is that so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

F# *does not* perform implicit conversions.

When type annotating in a `let` binding, the type must strictly match the expression.
For example,

```
let value : obj = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>()
```

will fail to compile, even though a `List` is very obviously an object.

When you write:

```
let implementer : IFirst = expr
```

The type of `expr` must absolutely be `IFirst`. There's no implicit casting like in C#.

An object expression will have its type as the abstract type implemented, so:

```
{ new ISecond with ... }
```

will be inferred to have a type of `ISecond`. Combine it with no-implicit casts rule, and you have a compile error.

Because `IFirst` and `ISecond` are unrelated, you could (runtime) downcast to `IFirst`:

```
let firstImplementer = implementer :?> IFirst
```

---

Another option is to make a combined interface:

```
type IBoth = inherit IFirst inherit ISecond
```

and do:

```
let implementer =
    {
        new IBoth with ...
```

That way you can freely (static) upcast to `IFirst` or `ISecond`.

```
let firstImplementer = implementer :> IFirst
let secndImplementer = implementer :> ISecond
```